# How to import and update the helm chart using terraform

Tags: terraform, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, terraform-provider-aws

After importing the helm to terraform, anything I am adding to values.YAML, it is considering as an addition, not a modification. Terraform is not using existing config to check for diff.

I tried to import the helm in Terraform using the below command:

```
terraform import helm_release.kube_prometheus_stack <namespace>/prometheus-stack
```

After successfully imported the helm, I ran `terraform plan` and I am passing the existing alerts in the values but Terraform is considering these alerts as a new addition. Ideally it should just show `no addition`

```
resource "helm_release" "kube_prometheus_stack" {
  name    = var.helm_release
  chart   = var.chart_name
  version = "XXXX"
  namespace = <namespace>

  values = [
    jsonencode(yamldecode(templatefile("alerts.yaml", {
      environment = var.environment
    })))
  ]
}
```